# Bundler::GemfileNotFound Error (Mac OSX)

Tags: ruby, octopress

```
MacBook-Air:~ bdeely$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.3.5...
MacBook-Air:~ bdeely$ rbenv rehash
MacBook-Air:~ bdeely$ bundle install
Bundler::GemfileNotFound
```

I keep getting this error "Bundler::GemfileNotFound" even after I have successfully installed bundler.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

For reference, I am following the directions here:
http://octopress.org/docs/setup/

Answer (score 0):

Create `Gemfile` in your directory.

Bundler is a gem manager. You should point somewhere which gems you need. The place is `Gemfile`.

[Article](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions that come with Octopress aren't clear, but the part where you `bundle install` has to be performed from within the Octopress directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip the first 3 step of cloning octopress:

```
git clone git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git octopress
cd octopress    # If you use RVM, You'll be asked if you trust the .rvmrc file (say yes).
ruby --version  # Should report Ruby 1.9.3
```

After that, your should in octopress folder and there is a `Gemfile` in it, now you can move on with `bundle install`